# Clip an Image and Show in Another Canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, typescript, fabricjs

I have two canvas on one page. I need to clip an image in first one and transfer it to second one as clipped.

I have a code like below but when i click to send i just see a black clipped image in second canvas. Plus, selectable area is big as before clipping.

```
  public clip() {
    var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('cLeft');
    let src = this.srcLeft;
    loadImage(src, canvas);

    // If there is enough width -> clipTo
    if (Math.abs(this.firstX - this.lastX) > 20 || Math.abs(this.firstY - this.lastY) > 20) {

      canvas.clipTo = (ctx) => {

        console.log("-->> clipTo: " + this.firstX + " " + this.firstY);

        var shp = new fabric.Rect({
          top: this.firstY,
          left: this.firstX,
          width: Math.abs(this.lastX - this.firstX),
          height: Math.abs(this.lastY - this.firstY),
          hasControls: false,
          selectable: false,
          evented: false
        });
        shp.render(ctx);
      };
      this.data = canvas.toDataURL();
    }
  }

  public send() {
    var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('cRight');
    fabric.Image.fromURL(this.data, function (img) {
      img.left = 10;
      img.top = 10;
      canvas.add(img);
      canvas.renderAll();
    })
  }
```

Comment: You don't need to use to canvas.toDataURL you can just render the first canvas onto the second.

Comment: Can i render just clipped area?

Comment: You can render any part. The canvas is just an image and can be rendered just like any image. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage will show you how.

Comment: So i should not pass whole canvas to second. Just rendered section.

Comment: So i must redraw image with selected area? I guess i got it.